# Shopify Scripts - New Line Item

Tags: shopify

I would like to add a new product (line item) via Shopify Scripts when a user uses a discount code. Is it possible?

```
if Input.cart.discount_code && Input.cart.discount_code.code == "first10"
    Input.cart.line_items << LineItem.new(variant: 24665166184512, quantity: 10, source_indices:false,grams: 0, properties_was:false, properties:false, line_price_was:false, line_price:50, original_line_price:50, discounts:0, adjustments:nil)
end

Output.cart = Input.cart
```

And I have error:

`[Error] undefined method 'id' for 24665166184512
  shopify/std_lib_mutable/core/resources/line_item.rb:164:in LineItem.to_hash
  shopify/std_lib_mutable/core/resources/cart.rb:43:in Cart.to_hash
  shopify/std_lib_mutable/cart_line_items/output.rb:4:in #<Class:0x7f85471e6280>.to_hash
  shopify/std_lib_mutable/cart_line_items/output.rb:4:in #<Class:0x7f85471e6280>.to_hash
  shopify/std_lib_mutable/core/script_kernel.rb:12:in Object.prepare_output
  (prepare_output):1`

Comment: Where do you see the **new** method for a LineItem in the docs? I am curious about that...

Comment: I don't see it. I found it by accident. For example, deleting a product from line_items doesn't exist in documentation but works.

`def delete_product(product_id)
  Input.cart.line_items.reject! { |line_item| line_item.variant.product.id == product_id || line_item.variant.id == product_id }
end`

Comment: You have to guess better than as to the requires params... your guess is off. And with no docs.. it means experimenting.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you cannot add products to a cart using Shopify Cart Scripts.

Cart scripts can only see and handle items that are already present in the cart.

as mentioned in comments, you can delete an item because it already exists in the cart.

My advise is to use either of these methods.

1) discount codes that when someone buys something they get another product at a certain price or free.

2) create an Ajax API script that when an item is added to the cart it looks up what items are in the cart and if the item is found then adds the free item or discounted item to the cart.

https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api

3) (PAID OPTION) is to have a look in the app market place and you can find a few different apps available to help you with this. this one looks like it might help you? https://apps.shopify.com/special-offers

Comment: This still stands true today. We cannot add new line items to carts from Shopify scripts. What I have done is applied a discount to the product when it is in the cart, then I used Rebuy app to auto-add the product if it doesn't exist.